# Several Problems with Flatlist in Chat. Flickering, reloading too often etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

Im new to React-Native and currently building a chat-function into my app. To visualize the chat Im using a FlatList (before I used Scrollview but with FlatList I have better performance with multiple items), netherless I have two big problems.

1. As I write more chatmessages more and more messages are getting appended to my chatmessages hook. One message is not a problem, but after 2 or 3 the whole FlatList starts to blink and reload. This gets worse if I append even more messages.
2. When I send more then 3 Messages to the Database, and they get downloaded by the firestore listener to my FlatList, those items arent even properly rendered into my FlatList. I use concat to add them **at the end of my chatmessages state** but FlatList displays them **at the beginning of the whole chat!** After that it blinks, and the new message drops one item lower, it blinks again and it drops lower, and this happens so long until the new message finally dropped to the end of the whole chat where it should be.
   It doesnt make sense at all because I use concat, so the new chatmessages are at the end of my whole chatmessages array, why is FlatList(and also Scrollview) adding them at the beginning and rerendering as much as they need to drop it to the bottom??

My Code looks like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, FlatList} from 'react-native'; 
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { Fontisto } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

import * as firebase from "firebase";

const ChatScreen = props => { 
    const chatId = props.navigation.getParam("chatId");
    const userId = useSelector(state => state.auth.userId);
    const partnerId = props.navigation.getParam("partnerId");
    const timekey = Date.now();
    const reloadkey = props.navigation.getParam("reloadkey");
    const [TItext, setTItext] = useState("");
    
    const[chatmessages, setChatMessages] = useState([{value: "", counter: 1, sender: "Kuba", key:"1291219293"}]);//dummydata before chat loads

    useEffect(() => {
        //fires only if you open the screen first time and no local chat stored is found. 
        retrieveChatFromAsyncStorage();
    }, [reloadkey])

    useEffect(() => {
        loadnewmessages();
    })
    
    const loadnewmessages = () =>{
        //loads new messages so they can be added to array of all chat messages
        // firestore onSnapshot listens to document changes the whole time. 
        console.log("LADE NEUE NACHRICHTEN");
        firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatId}`).collection(`${chatId}`).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            var newmessages = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                if(timekey < doc.data().timestamp){
                    newmessages.push({
                        counter: 1,
                        sender: doc.data().sender,
                        timestamp: doc.data().timestamp.toString(),
                        value: doc.data().value,
                    })
                }
            });
            //compare if a new message was updated or not. 
            //If there is a new one, length will be different of new and old array.
            if(newmessages.length > 0){
                setChatMessages(chatmessages.concat(newmessages));
                storeChatToAsyncStorage();

            }
        })
    };
    const loadallmessages = async () => { 
        //loads the last 20 messages and stores then in an array.
        //only gets executed once when chatwindow is opened
        console.log("LADE ALLE NACHRICHTEN");
        await firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatId}`).collection(`${chatId}`).orderBy("timestamp").limit(20).get().then(
            querySnapshot => {
                allChatMessages = [];
                querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    var quicksave = {
                        value: doc.data().value,
                        counter: doc.data().counter,
                        sender: doc.data().sender,
                        key: doc.data().timestamp.toString()
                    }
                    allChatMessages.push(quicksave);
                })
                setChatMessages(allChatMessages);
                storeChatToAsyncStorage();
                //console.log(allChatMessages);
            })
    };
    const pushMessagetoDB = async () => {
        //sending message to the chatroom in Firestore
        await firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatId}`).collection(`${chatId}`).add({
            "counter": 1,
            "sender": userId,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "value": TItext
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Chat written in DB!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error writing Chat into DB: ", error);
        });
    };
    const storeChatToAsyncStorage = async() => {
        try {
            const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(chatmessages);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(chatId, jsonValue);
            console.log("Chat saved!");
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    const retrieveChatFromAsyncStorage = async () => {
        console.log("LADEBACKUP");
        try {
            const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(chatId);
            const obj = JSON.parse(jsonValue);//convertiere zurück zu array mit objekten
            if(obj[0].key != "1291219293") {
                //lade in hook rein
                setChatMessages(obj);
            }else{
                console.log("Backup nicht gefunden. Downloade letzten 20 Nachrichten neu.");
                loadallmessages();
            }
          } catch(error) {//incase element doesnt exist.
            console.log("Problem beim Laden vom Backup!");
            loadallmessages();
          }
    };



    return(
        <View style={styles.Screen}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../components/pictures/welcome.png')} style={styles.backgroundChatImage}>
                <View style={styles.missingheader}/>
                <FlatList
                style={styles.chatwindow} 
                data={chatmessages}
                keyExtractor={(item) => {
                    return item.key
                }}
                renderItem={itemData => (
                    (itemData.item.sender == userId) ?  (
                        <View style={{flexWrap: "wrap-reverse", marginRight: 5}}>
                        <View style={{maxWidth:"47.5%", height:"auto", backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 120, 250, 0.7)", borderRadius: 5, paddingLeft: 5, marginBottom: 3}}>
                            <Text>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
                        </View>
                        </View> ) :
                    (itemData.item.sender == partnerId) ? (
                        <View style={{flexWrap: "wrap", marginLeft: 5}}>
                        <View style={{maxWidth:"47.5%", height:"auto", backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 120, 250, 0.7)", borderRadius: 5, paddingLeft: 5, marginBottom: 3}}>
                            <Text>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
                        </View>
                        </View>) : 
                    (
                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 5}}>
                        <View style={{width:"45%", height:"auto", backgroundColor: "rgba(57, 184, 0, 0.65)", borderRadius: 5, marginBottom: 3}}>
                            <Text style={{textAlign:"center", fontSize: 10}}>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
                        </View>
                        </View>)
                )}  
                />
                <View style={styles.bottom}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Fontisto name="photograph" size={24} color="orange" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TextInput 
                    style={{width:"75%", height:"90%", borderColor:"black", borderWidth:1, fontSize: 18, borderRadius: 10}}
                    value={TItext}
                    multiline
                    onChangeText={text => {setTItext(text)}}
                    >
                    
                    </TextInput>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{}} onPress={() => {
                        pushMessagetoDB();
                        setTItext("");
                        }}>
                        <FontAwesome name="send" size={24} color="orange"/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
};

/// NavigationOptions, nothing more. I think this doesnt matter for my problem.
ChatScreen.navigationOptions = props => {
    const PNickname = props.navigation.getParam("PNickname");
    const userPicUrl = props.navigation.getParam("userPicture");

    return {
        title: PNickname,
        headerShown: true, 
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor:"rgba(67, 154, 224, 1)",
        },
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontFamily: "AmaticBold",
            fontSize: 30,
            marginLeft: 25,
            color: "white"
        },
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerLeft: () => (
            <View style={{flexDirection:"row", alignItems:"center"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft:5}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        props.navigation.navigate("Contacts");
                    }} //!!! add a reload key so chats get reloaded when you get back
                >
                    <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={30} color="white"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Image source={{uri: userPicUrl}} style={{width:45, height:45, marginLeft:5, borderRadius: 10}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            
        )
    }
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Screen:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%"
    },
    missingheader:{
        height:"12.5%",
        width: "100%"
    },
    chatwindow:{
        height: "77.5%",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor:"rgba(52, 52, 52, 0)",
    },
    bottom:{
        height: "8%",
        width: "95%",
        backgroundColor:"rgba(67, 154, 224, 0.7)",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        borderRadius: 25,
        marginTop: 7
    },
    backgroundChatImage:{
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%",
        alignItems:"center"
    }
});

export default ChatScreen;
```

I have included several comments in the code, I hope those help. One thing I want to mention: The fact I make backups and store the chat to the AsyncStorage should not make any problems. I had this bug even before I implemented backups so this function is not the problem here.

I hope somebody as a good idea how to fix my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key issue here is with your `useEffect(() => loadnewmessages())`.  This is causing you a major performance overhead.

`useEffect` is a hook that has 2 parameters:

1. a "callback" - a function that will be run whenever the conditions (see #2)are met
2. dependency condition - one of 3 values:

   1. `null` (or omitted entirely) - the callback is run EVERY TIME the component renders
   2. `[]` (the empty array) - the callback is run only once when the component is first "mounted"
   3. `[var1, var2, .....]` - the callback is run if, each time the component is renders, any of the vars in the array has a different value than the last time the component rendered

In your case, you are fetching data from Firestore EVERY SINGLE TIME that the component renders.

Worse - each time your component renders you are using an `onSnapshot()` call meaning that you are creating a NEW realtime listener for data changes from that query every single time your component renders.  After 1 render, you'll have a single listener.  After you component renders a second time, you'll have 2 realtime listeners - each running the exact same Firestore query and listening for changes coming from Firestore.  After 3 renders, you have 3 realtime listeners ...

Worse again - your realtime listener(s) get data from Firestore and update state.  Updating state causes your component to re-render.  See previous paragraph(!!!)

I recommend you look at how React's useEffect should be used in conjunction with Firestore realtime listeners.  In particular, how to subscribe & unsubscribe to the listeners.  Look for the word "unsubscribe" in [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hooks-with-firebase-firestore/) for an example of `useEffect()` with Firestore (the section entitled "Streaming data in real time from Firestore as a side effect")

Comment: This was a very good comment, I really appriciate your time you put into this. Now that I fixed this issue, another problem came up unfortunately. Every time a new message gets received by loadnewmessages() , my whole FlatList gets resetted to the intial state of chatmessages hook which is placed at the beginning of the code. Im trying my best so somehow overcome this problem...

Comment: What I mean is that with loadallmessages() Im getting the newest 20 entries from the chat. This works perfectly, but as soon as I receive a new message all those 20 vanish and only the new ones are getting stored in the FlatList, even though I used setChatMessages() inside loadallmessages() to set the State and display those 20 messages inside the FlatList.